# How to Disable Specific Button rows in php

Tags: php

I want to disable the two buttons in a single row if the button will be clicked and won't affect the buttons of another row.

I dont know how to disable an echo button of the table. I want to disable the "Accept" and "Reject" button if one of those was been clicked.I provide a screenshot so that you can easily understand what I mean. Thank you in advance.

Here's my php code. It names as app.php

```
 <?php

   //connect to database

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

//select database
mysqli_select_db($con, 'appointment');

//select query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM service";

//Execute the query
$records = mysqli_query($con,$sql)

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Appointment Schedule</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width = "100%" border = "5px" height = "20%">
<tr align = "left">
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Middle Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>Contact No.</th>
    <th>Remarks</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
    echo "<tr><form action = 'display.php' method = post>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name=id value='".$row['ID']."'>";
    echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['mname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['address']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['time']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['office']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['services']."</td>";
    echo "<td><name = number>".$row['contactno']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['remarks']."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type =submit value='Accepted' name=accept>";
    echo "<td><input type =submit value='Rejected' name=reject>";
    echo "</form></tr>";    
}
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

here's my another one php code. It names display.php

```
<?php

//connect to database

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

//select database
mysqli_select_db($con, 'appointment');

if($_POST['accept'])
{
$sql = "UPDATE service SET remarks = 'Accepted' WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";

}

else if($_POST['reject'])
{
$sql = "UPDATE service SET remarks = 'Rejected' WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
}

//Execute Query
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    header("refresh:1; url=app.php");
else
    echo "Unsuccessful";
?>
```

here's the screenshot of my work

[Sample of my database table using php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZoLq.png)

[image: sample db table]

Comment: hello. I saw your source code. after you click accept or reject button, the web page will be refreshed. so do you want to disable one button after app.php page is refreshed?

Comment: If it's based off database permanent storage `<input type =submit value='Accepted' name=accept <?php if($row['remarks'] == 'Accepted') echo 'disabled'; ?> />` then do the same for the rejected button. Otherwise, javascript may be required.

Comment: hello sir..I want to disable the two button neither accept or reject will be clicked.

Comment: hello mr/ms Rasclatt, I tried your suggestion but it shows an error.

Comment: How do you want to disable them? if the `remarks` column is filled already then disable them both? Also, my snippet is an example, it wouldn't be just copied and pasted as is, you have concatenated strings so you have to adjust for that.

Comment: Yes sir/maam, I want to disable them both if one of them was been clicked and the remarks column has filled in.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. You should parameterize the queries.

Comment: @chris85 how can I parameterize the queries sir?I am newbie in this language.

Comment: I also want to disable the two buttons of the specific row and won't affect other buttons of the next row.Thank you

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. Your query should have no variables in it. You also could simplify that if you gave the `reject`/`accept` the same `input` name. You then can just use the value for the `update`. e.g. something like `UPDATE service SET remarks = ? WHERE ID=?` then bind in `$_POST[id]` and whatever you name the remarks `input`, probably `remark`.

Comment: @chris85 I still can't understand sir. Can you please show me some example codes sir? I'm so sorry sir, i'm newbie in this language.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try the below code:
Provide the condition to display the buttuon

```
echo "<td><input type =submit value='Accepted' name=accept>";
echo "<td><input type =submit value='Rejected' name=reject>";
if($row['remarks'] == 'Accepted' || $row['remarks'] == 'Rejected')
{
    echo "<td><input type =submit disabled value='Accepted' name=accept>";
    echo "<td><input type =submit disabled value='Rejected' name=reject>";
}
```

Comment: hello sir, I tried your code but it creates another two another accept/reject button that cant be clicked.

Comment: Put the below code in else part:
else
{
    echo "<td><input type =submit value='Accepted' name=accept>"; 
    echo "<td><input type =submit value='Rejected' name=reject>";
}